# How to send push notification on mobile app with capacitorJS without third party like firebase or onesignal

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, service-worker, sveltekit, mobile-development

I have an app in which I'm using sveltekit with static adapter to build a mobile application using CapacitorJS,
I would like to send push notifications from the server to the client app but I don't want to use any third party like firebase, one signal etc, Please is there any means that would help, I read about service worker but not sure how it would work, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i don't understand clearly your question, but why you can't use  capacitor solution for push notifications ?
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications

Comment: Definitely going to use CapacitorJS push notification but it requires using firebase or another third party to trigger push notification from the backend.